# Change Java swing mac dock tooltip text

Tags: java, macos, swing

I'm developing a simple Java swing application and of-course I'm noob learning java . When I run that program it shows "java" text tool-tip on mac dock .

[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oGDM.png)

How can i remove that text and replace with my own text . I tried this code but it doesn't work .
the code i tried :

```
System.setProperty("com.apple.mrj.application.apple.menu.about.name", "My text");
```

thanks in advance .

Comment: You my need to supply an app bundle, something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24978212/jar-to-mac-osx-app-bundle-with-app-bundler/24992828#24992828)

Comment: The other option might be to use the -Xdock:name parameter, demonstrated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24977637/adding-menubar-space-on-mac/24977799#24977799)

Comment: More [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21591491/230513).

Comment: Thanks @MadProgrammer , worked ! :)