# How to Hide a Java application in Mac programatically?

Tags: java, macos, swing

i'm making a java application for mac. the application must have the hability of "Auto Hide" equals to "Command+H" shortcut. i'm trying to do it using setVisible(False) in the JFrame. but it doesn't work. how can i do it?

this is may code:

```
void hide(){
   setNormalScreen(); //disable fullscreen mode
   //this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
   setVisible(false);
   this.setState(JFrame.ICONIFIED);
}
```

and this is what i'm getting:
[image: The main window]

Comment: Wrap your JAR in an Mac OS X application bundle, discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14917990/230513) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8956715/230513).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the below example.  You can hide it via Java code using `setVisible(false)` as you suggested, then `appReOpened()` event will be called when the user clicks the app in the dock.  When this happens, you can just call `setVisible(true)`.  This should mimic the Command-H behavior.

See the commented code below also for an uglier solution.

```
public class Test extends JFrame implements ActionListener, com.apple.eawt.AppReOpenedListener {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test frame = new Test();
        JButton test = new JButton("test");
        test.addActionListener(frame);

        com.apple.eawt.Application app = com.apple.eawt.Application.getApplication();
        app.addAppEventListener(frame);

        frame.getContentPane().add(test);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        setVisible(false);

        //      try {
        //          Robot robot = new Robot();
        //          robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_META);
        //          robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_H);
        //          robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_H);
        //          robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_META);
        //      } catch (AWTException ex) {
        //          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        //          ex.printStackTrace();
        //      }
    }

    @Override
    public void appReOpened(AppReOpenedEvent arg0) {
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. after a little more research, I realized that setVisible does not work if the application is in full screen, just so I have to wait until the application returns to normal and then I can do the trick robot

Comment: Is it possible when it hide to dock and a timer implements here during minimize will work perfectly, or timer does not get stuck.