# JAR bundler not found in MAC PC after installing JDK

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, jarbundler

I am developing an admin application in JAVA that is supposed to run in all platform. For this application I need to create an installer. But I am facing some problems in MAC. In order create installer in MAC I need to bundle JAR file. But I don't find any JAR bundler in my PC though I have setup the latest JDK. Can someone help me to get the JAR bundler? Please specify the full process to get JAR bundler.

NOTE: I am developing the app using eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

The solution of this problem can be found in the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375490/why-is-jar-bundler-gone-in-mac-os-x-mountain-lion-10-8-2?rq=1). Apparently, Apple has discontinued the existence of JAR bundler.

Answer (score 1):

JarBundler is obsolete, but there is a (better) official replacement: the [javapackager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/packager.html) tool.

For OSX, A simple, well explained, step by step tutorial on how to create a DMG from java is here: http://centerkey.com/mac/java/ .