# UnsupportedClassVersionError java

Tags: java, eclipse, unsupported-class-version

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Exception in thread “main” java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: a (Unsupporte d major.minor version 51.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237536/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-a-unsupporte)

I have been using Eclipse with jre 1.7.x and jdk 1.7.x before and I had to downgrade to 1.6x.

The way that I downgraded was to uninstall all the 1.7 related from my computer and install 1.6 again.

Now, when I try to debug, I am getting

```
`java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: MyClass: Unsupported major.minor version 51.0`
```

I checked the version of JRE and JDK that used to compiled, both of them are 1.6.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Did you do a clean build of the Eclipse project after downgrading Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: `Unsupported major.minor version 51.0`
```

Your runtime version is different from compile time version.

Make sure `JAVA_HOME` variables etc., to make sure compile and runtime both pointing to same version.

Answer (score 0):

take a look here [How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0)

you compiled code with 1.7 and debugging with 1.6