# UnsupportedClassVersionError while running Java program

Tags: java, netbeans

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Exception in thread “main” java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: a (Unsupported major.minor version 51.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237536/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-a-unsupporte)

My Java program which I run on Mac & Windows is not working. Instead I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: menus/Main_Screen : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using the `-source` and `-target` flags to specify the bytecode version you want?  E.g. `-target 6`.

Answer (score 3):

Class version 51.0 is generated by Java 7.

You're trying to run with an earlier version, probably Java 6. 
You need to call the Java 7 version of the java command.

The version used to run NetBeans is set in NetBeans/etc/netbeans.conf.
The version used to build and run a project is set by the project properties.
You can tell NetBeans about a new Java version through the Tools > Java Platforms

Comment: sorry, but how to do it? cos im not very familiar with it

Comment: Install the latest JDK (1.7u11, at the moment) from here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Comment: Alternatively, in NB, right click your project, choose properties, and change target/binary to JDK-6

Answer (score 0):

```
Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(
```

It seems your java runtime version is different (lower) version from compile time version.

Comment: what is the solution? how to change it? i have 3 main classes

Comment: Make sure Java version on Mac is same as Java version on your windows.

Answer (score 0):

The general rule is this.

If take a *.class compiled by a version of Java EARLIER than the JRE, it should work in that JRE. 
Because the later JRE is supposed to "know" previous versions of format.

If take a *.class compiled by a version of Java LATER than the JRE, it should not work in that JRE. 
Because the earlier JRE is not supposed to know the future versions of format.

---

In your case the code is simply compiled by the version of Java issued after the version of the JRE.