# exceptions on executing hdfs namenode -format

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I get following exception, when I execute `hdfs namenode -format` command:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/hadoop/util/PlatformName : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: org.apache.hadoop.util.PlatformName.  Program will exit.
```

Comment: Check below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237536/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-a-unsupporte Update java alternatives

Comment: @Krishna can you help me in finding the hadoop eclipse plugin for hadoop version 2.7.1

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to java version mismatch i.e the version with which hadoop is compiled is higher than the jdk version installed on your machine.Install proper jdk version and set JAVA_HOME properly

Comment: server ipc version 9 cannot communicate with client version 3, I am getting this error in DFS path when i connect in eclipse. hadoop version I m using is 2.7.1 and eclipse hadoop plugin I have added is of 0.20.2, why is that error?